# enable server side encryption for dynamodb using cloudformation yaml

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, aws-cloudformation

can someone help me on how to enable a server side encryption to DynamoDB  using yaml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DynamoDB is **encrypted at rest by default**. Thus there is nothing to enable, nor you can't disable [it](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/EncryptionAtRest.html):

> All user data stored in Amazon DynamoDB is **fully encrypted at rest**.

However, if you don't want to use AWS owned customer master key (CMK)  for encryption, you can use **your own CMK** from [KMS](https://aws.amazon.com/kms/).

To specity your own key there is [SSESpecification](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-dynamodb-table-ssespecification.html#cfn-dynamodb-table-ssespecification-sseenabled) option in CloudFormation:

```
SSESpecification:
  KMSMasterKeyId: <your-kms-key-id>
  SSEEnabled: true
  SSEType: KMS
```

Comment: thanks @Marcin...
and also is there a role going to access them have permissions to encrypt and decrypt